# Is it possible to allow users to create files/folders and prevent deleting folders?

Tags: windows-7, security, file-management, file-sharing

I have a Windows 7 computer that has several users. I have a parent folder that is shared with the users. I want certain users to be able to create files/folders within this parent folder. However, I do not want them to be able to delete those files/folders. Is this possible? Also, when they create a new folder, they need to be able to rename it.

Comment: The owner of a directory can also delete it. When creating a new directory, the creator by defaul becomes the owner of that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Securtity tab, you need to add the group **Creator Owner**. This group statically assigns permissions to who ever the **first** owner of the object is.

Edit:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780823(v=ws.10).aspx

Note the Drop Folder which is similar to your scenario.

> Drop folder. A folder where users can drop confidential reports or homework assignments that only the group manager or instructor can read.

Basically, those who create the objects need different permissions from others.